# Windows NPS: Policy should check Issuing CA

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, radius

I have some trouble in configuring a Windows NPS, maybe anybody of you have an idea.

Is it possible for NPS to check whether a client certificate was signed by a specific issuing CA?

I have two SSIDs (SSID-1, SSID-2)
I have one Root-CA and two different Issuing CAs (I-1, I-2)

A Client that comes with a certificate that was signed by I-2 must not use 
SSID-1

To manage that, my idea was to check which issuing CA comes with the certificate chain.
I think NPS also has  to check the Calling-Station-ID Attribute to get the SSID.

### Example:

SSID-1? Yes

AND

Certificate chain has I-1? Yes

OK you are in!

Do you have an idea?
By the way I have no Active Directory in the background.

Thanks!